# Can a barbarian activate reckless attack after the attack roll has been made?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

I was looking at the reckless attack feature and it's not clear to me whether or not reckless attack can be used after the barbarian has already rolled their d20.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, the barbarian must declare he is using **reckless attack** before he rolls any dice.

> **When you make your first attack** on your turn, you can decide to attack
>   recklessly.
>   
>   Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using
>   Strength during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage
>   until your next turn....

Emphasis mine.

You must declare that you are using reckless attack when you make your attack, not after you have hit on your attack.  Advantage is applied when you make the initial attack roll.  The ability does not allow you to apply it after you roll one die, decide that it isn't good enough, and want to add another -- that's simply not how advantage works.

The point is whether you hit or miss, attacks will have advantage against you until your next turn.

Comment: Also important to note how this interacts with Bonus Action attacks, Extra Attack, etc, is as specified, you have to declare Reckless Attack on the **first** attack you make on your turn, otherwise you can't use it that turn.

Comment: @Randomorph That is explicit in the quoted text, "when you make your first attack..."